# Prettify using beautifulsoup without adding line breaks

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, indentation

Say I have an HTML file like this

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Some post</p>
<p>Another post</p>
</body>
</html>
```

In python I can use `soup.prettify()` to adjust line indentation. However, prettify adds additional line breaks. The output looks like this

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   Some post
  </p>
  <p>
   Another post
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I would like to add indentation only, without adding additonal line breaks (equivalent to the effect "Reindent" has in Sublime Text). That is, I would like to output to look like this

```
<html>
<body>
    <p>Some post</p>
    <p>Another post</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Can this be done in python?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable additional line breaks for certain tags using the `preserve_whitespace_tags` keyword argument:

```
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_html, preserve_whitespace_tags=["p"])
```

Documentation: `bs4.builder.TreeBuilder.__init__`

> A list of tags to treat
> the way  tags are treated in HTML. Tags in this list
> are immune from pretty-printing; their contents will always be
> output as-is.

However, there doesn't seem to be a "don't add any whitespace" option. The [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#pretty-printing) even states:

> Since it adds whitespace (in the form of newlines), prettify() changes the meaning of an HTML document and should not be used to reformat one.

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping there is a way to do this in python. Any other command line option would be welcome.

Comment: How has no one congratulated you by upvoting this yet!? `preserve_whitespace_tags` is practically undocumented, yet, exactly what I was trying to do. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.